# How to edit "Show Applications" menu

Tags: gnome, icons, gui

I understand there's a similar question of how to edit the applications menu but it doesn't work for me. Both Alacarte and Menulibre don't show icons that are stuck in my "Show applications" menu.

The icons of deleted apps won't disappear and I know there's a way to go into some obscure folder on my drive and remove the entries. Is there a normal-human-oriented way, possible via a program like those that are mentioned above to edit the menu?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RXeS.png)

Comment: Sometimes after an app gets removed the shortcut is still in cache and needs to be cleared.  Try pressing Alt+F2, then enter `r` and press enter to restart the desktop.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, full restart too. And also one of the icons has changed :D

Comment: You can also look in the directory of `/usr/share/applications` for the matching `.desktop` files for the ones that you deleted and remove the `.desktop` file if one exists.  They can also be found in `~/.local/share/applications` directory as well.

Comment: Yeah, they were there and after removal they're gone. But I was wondering if there's an app or extension for that. If there's none, maybe you can write one? I would literally pay you if that was the case